# Adjust photo macro to change format

Tags: macros, graphics

Using the LaTeX CV template available under [this Link](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5cc4ad09b600dd7932d81544) (login: gafavekor@cyber-host.net ; pw: 123456) and I've realized that the picture is automatically cut to a vertical format. I would just like my picture to be displayed as is, which is horizontal. As far as I can tell, the template uses these commands to insert the picture:

```
\newcommand{\photo}[2]{\def\@photo{#2}\def\@photodiameter{#1}}
\photo{2.5cm}{DCE2small2}
```

To use my own, I've deleted the DCE2small2.jpg and inserted my picture which I then named DCE2small2.jpg.

How can I change this to maintain the format of the .jpg?

Comment: Please do not post just a code snippet, but a complete MWE. To access the linked document, a login is required.

Comment: Why not just use `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @erik I am not using \includegraphics because then, the figure does not stay in the same row as the social information (name, tel, email etc.). I found solutions like the package wrapfig, but they require the text to be written somewhere below the \includegraphics part. Currently, it is done very differently (  \photo{}
    \socialinfo{}
are before
    \begin{document}) and I assumed that it's easier just to change the macro slightly.

Comment: Are you using the AltaCV class? If so, add the `normalphoto` option to `documentclass`.

Comment: @erik the documentclass is defined by \documentclass[localFont,alternative]{documentMETADATA}

Comment: I could have hit the "trash bin" whilst in there! Regardless the code as you know has been modified from equal proportions of a circle to a vertical rectangle like a passport photo that is it is self healing and automatically adjusts itself to suit the image so just make the image square or wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is based on [yaac-another-awesome-cv](https://github.com/darwiin/yaac-another-awesome-cv), and places the photo in a shaped defined by Ti*k*Z.

```
\newcommand\idphoto{
  \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={\@photo}]rectangle (\linewidth,1.2\linewidth);
}
```

If using a photo that's wider than it is tall, the photo is masked.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[alternative]{documentMETADATA}
\name{Jane}{Doe}
\tagline{Electrical Engineer | Instructor}
\photo{4cm}{example-image-16x9}
\socialinfo{
    \email{email@email.edu}
}
\begin{document}
\makecvheader
\end{document}
```

[image]

To avoid this, you can redefine `\idphoto` to simply use `\includegraphics`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[alternative]{documentMETADATA}
\name{Jane}{Doe}
\tagline{Electrical Engineer | Instructor}
\photo{4cm}{example-image-16x9}
\socialinfo{
    \email{email@email.edu}
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\idphoto{%
\includegraphics[width=\@photodiameter,height=\@photodiameter,keepaspectratio]{\@photo}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvheader
\end{document}
```

[image]